# SSH port forwarding not working remotely

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ssh, router, port-forwarding

I am trying to build a server with my old PC just out of curiosity. I installed ubuntu 21.10. And connected it with Real VNC. Now I need to connect it with ssh. I can connect to the PC via the local network, but when I try to connect from an external network it did not connect.

After researching I got to know I have to enable port forwarding for my router. When I try to do that the router's admin panel's login details were changed by the provider and they forgot the details. And refusing to reconfigure by resetting the router.

Now I connected another old modem DSL-2750u and connected it as a wifi extender and changed its default IP address. And tried to port forward through it. And enabled port forwarding in ubuntu.

I added the PC mac address to be static by assigning it a default id in the DHCP reservation section. My PC local IP address is 192.168.1.8. But in the end, it is not connecting.

This is my router port forwarding table
[image: 1]

This is firewall info in the system
[image: 2]

This is ssh status info
[image: 3]

Please help me with this issue where my doing is wrong, I am a newbie, trying to learn how servers work and configured

Comment: I'd recommend that you rethink your whole approach. Building a server from an old PC is definitely not advisable for a business environment.

Comment: Port forwarding would only work on the router connected to the ISP directly.

Comment: @TilmanSchmidt thank you for your advice. I am not trying to deploy any business environments. Just trying to learn how this works

Comment: In that case you have come to the wrong place. StackExchange is specifically for questions regarding management of IT systems in a business environment.

Answer (score 0):

If ssh is working then you should rewrite some options on router. First up is local ip address - you should change it to all (if you have that option). Also change wan port to all. If that still doesn't work check if your machine is blocking client ip address. I also recommend visiting [Port forwarding Tester](https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/) to check if the port on your router is actually opened.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As you said I looked for changing IP to all, there is no option for that. And tried to ping from the client PC with the public IP of the server, if the server is blocking it, the client received packets from the server. And finally checked the website you mentioned, it returned that port 22 is closed